# Are user browser information and ip address available as tokens in Rules?

Tags: 7, rules, tokens

I am sending an email to admin from contact form. In the email I want to send the user browser information like browser name and version and the user ip address. But I'm unable to see the tokens for these values?

I want the browser info and ip address for both logged-in and anonymous users.

Are these tokens available in the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module? Or I will have to create custom tokens?

Answer (score 3):

Use `[current-user:ip-address]` token for IP address of the current user.

For browser related token you have generate it using **token_generate** API.

> function **token_generate** use to generates replacement values for a list of tokens.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd enable the [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) module (disclosure: I'm its maintainer), it would already capture the info you're looking for.

Here is just a random pick of such capture info:

- **URL**: http://www.example.com/some/path
- **Title**: Some title
- **Referer**: http://www.example.com/some/referer/path
- **Date**: Wed, 07/27/2016 - 10:43
- **User**: Some.User
- **IP**: 111.222.333.444
- **User Agent**:   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36

This info can be used to displayed it to authorized users visiting the site, whereas you could include an appropriate link to the relevant [Visitors](https://www.drupal.org/project/visitors) info in the eMail you want to send (using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module).

Answer (score -1):

if you want browser info them use this...

```
<code> <iframe src="http://ulvis.net/browser.php"></iframe></code>
```

look like [image]

Comment: That works in the browser, but cannot be sent by email.

Comment: sorry ,my fault , i fast read text even don't  see he need  send to email info.